# To set a random pause time between every request in the Gatling Simulation

Tags: scala, gatling

How can we set a random pause time between every request in the Gatling Simulation.

By defining the below method I am able to get a random response time.

```
    def minPause = 100.milliseconds
    def maxPause = 500.milliseconds
```

But in this case, I will have to call it whenever I need the pause time.

Is there a way to set random pause time between every request at the global level?

Answer (score 1):

Please [read the documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/#pause), there's a built-in for uniform pauses:

```scala
// Uniform random pause duration:
pause(minPause, maxPause)
```

Then, there's no built-in way to automatically add a pause after each request. You can either specify one or create a helper method.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you @Stephane LANDELLE